# NEXT.JS - Проблема с отправкой FormData на сервер

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование, nextjs, formdata

Есть веб-приложение, серверная часть которого написана на NestJS, клиентская - NextJS 13. На одной из страниц присутствует форма, в которую загружается изображение или видео.

```js
"use client"

export const CreateSlideForm = () => {
  const [file, setFile] = useState < File > ();
  const [type, setType] = useState < "img" | "video" | null > (null);
  const [fileError, setFileError] = useState("");
  const [typeError, setTypeError] = useState("");
  const router = useRouter();

  const onSubmit = async() => {
    try {
      setFileError("");
      setTypeError("");

      if (!type) setTypeError("Укажите тип файла");
      if (!file) setFileError("Загрузите файл");

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", file as Blob);
      formData.append("type", type as string);

      axios.post("http://localhost:4200/api/about-us", formData, {
        method: "POST",
      }).then((res) => router.push("/"))
      router.push("/");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  return ( 
    <form className = {styles.form}>
      <RadioButton label = "Фото"
        name = "photo-radio"
        checked = {type === "img"}
        onChange = {() => setType("img")}
        error = {typeError}
      /> 
      <RadioButton 
        label = "Видео"
        name = "video-radio"
        checked = {type === "video"}
        onChange = {() => setType("video")}
        error = {typeError}
      /> 
      <UploadFile 
        name = "file"
        label = {`Загрузите ${type === "img" ? "фото" : type === "video" ? "видео" : "файл"}`}
        onChange = {(e) => setFile((e.target.files as any)[0])}
        error = {fileError}
      /> 
      <Button 
        variant = {ButtonVariantsEnum.orange}
        type = "submit"
        className = "admin-btn"
        onClick = {onSubmit} 
      > Создать </Button> 
    </form>
  )
}
```

При клике на кнопку функция отрабатывает, запрос отправляется и приходит ответ со статус-кодом 200, НО происходит редирект на ту же страницу, с которой отправляется запрос (http://localhost:3000/admin/slide/create? - иногда с вопросительным знаком на конце) и возвращается ошибка:

- Failed to fetch RSC payload. Falling back to browser navigation.
  TypeError: Failed to fetch at fetchServerResponse

При активации троттлинга через Chrome Dev Tools данные не отправляются совсем (статус запроса - отменен), ошибок при этом в консоли не наблюдается:
[image: Ошибка без троттлинга]

[image: Запрос с троттлингом]

Я отправлял другие запросы на сервер (в том числе с этой страницы), и все шло хорошо. Но как только появился запрос с FormData, начали происходить непонятные мне вещи. Полагаю, проблема именно в формдате (если не брать в расчет мою криворукость)